# how to remove all rows of a tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can anyone tell me that how to remove all rows of a tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the datasource (for example `[dataSourceMutableArray removeAllObjects]`) and reload the table (`[tableView reloadData]`)

Comment: No actually i am using  all code inside following-----
if(cell==nil)
 {

}

so the rows not show that data  when i reload them

Comment: Reconsider your design then. Anyway, you can "remove" all rows by making sure tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returns 0 and calling reloadData.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove all values in dataSource of tableView? Then reload the tableView

Comment: Actually my cell are fixed look at the comment given to @ssteinberg

so when i reload the table with new values it does not replace them

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 0;

}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0;

}
```

or specify `return nil;` instead of `return cell;` in `cellForRowAtIndextPath` function

or you can remove all values in array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    // remove below line
    //cell.textlabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indextPath];

    return cell;
}
```